# Installed Ubuntu on a separate HDD, got a grub error and want to know if anything went wrong

Tags: installation, windows, raid, grub2

I installed Ubuntu on my spare HDD and everything was going fine until the setup installed GRUB. I have 3 HDDs in RAID0 and a spare HDD where I chose for Ubuntu. The error said that GRUB cannot be installed on drive named "sda", therefore I picked "sdd" from the list, which was the HDD with Ubuntu on it. As I went through the list of drives, I noticed a few volumes with "mapper" in their name, which I assumes is the RAID0. Afterwards, even though it was installed on a separate drive, I had to use the /fixmbr windows recovery to be able to boot into windows.

My question is, why did it still affect windows if it was installed on a separate drive? When it was trying to install on "sda", does that mean it might have corrupted my windows partition and data?

Comment: Hard to know where you are at right now, sounds as if you re-installed the windows boot loader ? Can you tell us what grub error exactly.

Comment: Yes I reinstalled the bootloader for windows so that I am able to boot again, which is weird since it's on a separate drive. As for grub, it was a message box with 3 choices, first being to change where grub is to be installed, second to install without a bootloader and third to cancel the installation.

Comment: You should be able to install grub to the same hard drive as Ubuntu, then when you boot, does your bios allow you to select which drive to boot from ? If so, select the one with Ubuntu. Alternately, you should be able to go with the defaults and install grub to the MBR of your first hard drive.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. It tried installing it on "sda" which didn't exist, so I chose "sdd". My only concern now is since the bootloader on windows was affected, is there any possibility of other data being corrupted, or is the bootloader the only thing affected?

Comment: Ubuntu should not have affected windows outside of your grub / boot issues.

Comment: If that's the case then I guess there is nothing to worry about and since I fixed the bootloader, it should be fine. Thank you so much for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing should have gone wrong if I understand your situation correctly. Sometimes it is easy to confuse which HDD you are installing on - hence why you got GRUB on the wrong HDD.

If you have fixed the mbr of Windows, then you should not have any other problems.